# R Updating A Column In a Large Dataframe

Tags: r, csv, optimization, chess

I've got a dataframe, which is stored in a csv, of 63 columns and 1.3 million rows. Each row is a chess game, each column is details about the game (e.g. who played in the game, what their ranking was, the time it was played, etc). I have a column called "Analyzed", which is whether someone later analyzed the game, so it's a yes/no variable.

I need to use the API offered by chess.com to check whether a game is analyzed. That's easy. However, how do I systematically update the csv file, without wasting huge amounts of time reading in and writing out the csv file, while accounting for the fact that this is going to take a huge amount of time and I need to do it in stages? I believe a best practice for chess.com's API is to use Sys.sleep after every API call so that you lower the likelihood that you are accidentally making concurrent requests, which the API doesn't handle very well. So I have Sys.sleep for a quarter of a second. If we assume the API call itself takes no time, then this means this program will need to run for 90 hours because of the sleep time alone. My goal is to make it so that I can easily run this program in chunks, so that I don't need to run it for 90 hours in a row.

The code below works great to get whether a game has been analyzed, but I don't know how to intelligently update the original csv file. I think my best bet would be to rewrite the new dataframe and replace the old Games.csv every 1000 or say API calls. See the commented code below.

My overall question is, when I need to update a column in csv that is large, what is the smart way to update that column incrementally?

```
library(bigchess)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)

df <- read.csv <- "Games.csv"

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  data <- read_json(df$urls[i])
  if(data$analysisLogExists == TRUE){
    df$Analyzed[i] <- 1
  }
  if(data$analysisLogExists==FALSE){
    df$Analyzed[i] = 0
  }
  Sys.sleep(.25)

##This won't work because the second time I run it then I'll just reread the original lines 
##if i try to account for this by subsetting only the the columns that haven't been updated,
##then this still doesn't work because then the write command below will not be writing the whole dataset to the csv
if(i%%1000){
    write.csv(df,"Games.csv",row.names = F)
  }

}
```

Comment: One possibility for you is to learn about `data.table` which is pretty designed for just that: by reference modification of `data.frame` alike objects by extending `data.frame` functionality.  It you can make a mock version of `Games.csv` available somewhere I (or others) can probably help you some more.  There are _lots_ of excellent `data.table` threads here too.

Comment: Otherwise you could also switch to file-backed operations via `RSQLite` or `duckdb`.  But `data.table` is great, and `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` are quick for binary dumps.